# Instagram Access Token Expiring

Tags: instagram-api

I have got the Instagram API integrated to get the users' data who authorize the App. I find sometimes that the tokens become invalid after sometime. But there is no specific timeline. I have around 1200 users who have authorized and out of them 470 have invalid tokens.

I checked the Instagram documentation also - https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/ and it says Access tokens can expire anytime. I believe that the users don't revoke the access to my App. So it is Instagram who is expiring the tokens. I understand that we need to check the tokens and ask user to reconnect if that happens but just not sure whether that is the issue.

Does anyone face similar issue and is there any other way apart from asking user to reconnect ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On that page that you linked there is a box that is highlighted and says **important**

> your app should handle the case that either the user revokes access,
>   or Instagram expires the token after some period of time.

So user either revokes access or token expires.

*"I understand that we need to check the tokens and ask user to reconnect if that happens but just not sure whether that is the issue."*
 - what issue are you referring too?

No there would be no other way to reconnect a user to instagram other than to get them to reconnect.

Comment: - what issue are you referring too?
>> I am referring to Instagram expiring tokens itself.
Any idea when it happens and why it happens ?

Comment: No and no. Instagram dont give any indication why.